# Why is RTT to a host much slower than serving an HTTP page from the same host?

Tags: http, networking

I am hosting an HTTP page behind CloudFront, Amazon AWS's CDN. From my location, a typical request to this page competes in less than 20 milliseconds:

```
$ ab http://d2szlqeo43tgz6.cloudfront.net/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking d2szlqeo43tgz6.cloudfront.net (be patient).....done


Server Software:        AmazonS3
Server Hostname:        d2szlqeo43tgz6.cloudfront.net
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js
Document Length:        84345 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   0.014 seconds
Complete requests:      1
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      84887 bytes
HTML transferred:       84345 bytes
Requests per second:    70.14 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       14.258 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       14.258 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          5814.10 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        1    1   0.0      1       1
Processing:    13   13   0.0     13      13
Waiting:        4    4   0.0      4       4
Total:         14   14   0.0     14      14
```

Whereas if I try to measure RTT via `ping`, the times are much greater than 20 ms:

```
$ ping d2szlqeo43tgz6.cloudfront.net
PING d2szlqeo43tgz6.cloudfront.net (54.230.149.139): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 54.230.149.139: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=77.230 ms
64 bytes from 54.230.149.139: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=79.888 ms
64 bytes from 54.230.149.139: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=96.338 ms
64 bytes from 54.230.149.139: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=76.166 ms
```

So how can CloudFront serve HTTP content so much faster than it can respond to an ICMP echo request?

Just to be sure, I checked the response in Wireshark, and all HTTP content is coming from the network; no local cache is involved.